# Android soft keyboard hides the input filed in the bottom of the screen. Need to scroll to bottom manually

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have `EditText` in the last row and when I tap on it in order to put text in it, auto popup keypad opens and it hides the last content on my screen. I do not have any `ScrollView` in my layout. 
I am using `xamarin-adroid`. Anyone has solution for it?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept my answer. If not, can you give us an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at activities their `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute which you can declare in the manifest as such:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Alternatively, you could specify the soft input mode for one activity using an Activity attribute as such:

```
[Activity (
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
public class ExampleActivity : Activity
{
}
```

Comment: but adding it in manifest file will affect all activities, i am having issue on a particular screen. any thoughts?

Comment: @Tayyab I have updated my answer, please let me know if this fits your needs.